# Normal to a curve at the point x=1

Tags: calculus, derivatives, differential-geometry, implicit-differentiation

Find the equation to the normal of the curve $y=x-\frac{2}{x^2}$
 at the point where $x=1$. Then show that the normal does not meet the curve again.

I'm not sure what to do. I understand that you differentiate then sub in the x value but as there is no Y value im not sure how to do it. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean $$y=\frac{x-2}{x^2}$$?

Comment: The $y$ value you get of course by the equation that you wrote. Do you know how to form the equation of the normal line?

Comment: The equation is y = x-(2/x^2) I have found the y value and used it to get the equation of the normal as y=-1/5x-4/5. But how do you show it will never meet the curve again

Comment: Hint: equate normal to the curve and show there is only one intersection point $(1,-1)$.

Comment: @OwenLiggins Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

We have

- $y=x-\frac{2}{x^2}\implies y(1)=-1$
- $y'=1+\frac 4 {x^3}\implies y'(1)=5$

then the normal at $P(1,-1)$ is

$$y-(-1)=-\frac15(x-1)\implies y=-\frac15 x-\frac45$$

Now we need to show that the interscetion

- $y=x-\frac{2}{x^2}$
- $y=-\frac15 x-\frac45$

has only one solution.

Comment: Someone changed the equation! That isnt the equation i said $y=x-\frac{2}{x^2}$ not $y=\frac{x-2}{x^2}$

Comment: @OwenLiggins ok I update the derivation